# Connect a camera to the pi and get the video stream from it sent to an external (self powered) HDD

Tags: camera

First off, How do I connect to the camera? it is a YALE WiFi internal security camera.

Then I want to save the output from the camera to a Networked HDD which I already use to capture video to the HDD but these are external cameras and they have settings in the 'Management section' which allow me to direct the output to the ip address of my pi (which then sends the video to my HDD (via code I have written).

Is it possible to do?

Thanks